# Install previous version of Pycharm (snap)

Tags: 18.04, snap, pycharm

Is it not possible to install an older version of Pycharm community using snap?

I tried `snap install pycharm-community=2018.2.5` but it does not work.

Answer (score 9):

It is possible. You have to inform to snap which channel you want to download the version from.
In order to find the channel a.k.a version you do:

`snap info pycharm-community`

This is gonna give an output with information about this snap with a session including all available channels.
Example of this session:

```
channels:
  stable:           2019.3.2   2020-01-22 (175) 364MB classic
  candidate:        2019.3.3   2020-01-31 (177) 364MB classic
  beta:             2019.3.3   2020-01-31 (177) 364MB classic
  edge:             2020.1-EAP 2020-01-27 (176) 429MB classic
  2020.1/stable:    –                                 
  2020.1/candidate: –                                 
  2020.1/beta:      –                                 
  2020.1/edge:      2020.1-EAP 2020-01-27 (176) 429MB classic
  2019.3/stable:    2019.3.2   2020-01-22 (175) 364MB classic
```

After you choose the channel matching with the version you want, do:

`snap switch --channel 2019.2/stable pycharm-community`

This will tell snap to look to this channel for updates.
After that run the command to install the version from that channel:

`snap refresh pycharm-community`

This will disable the current version as it was uninstalled and make the new active.

Answer (score 0):

As per the time of writing the only solution I have found is to uninstall (`snap remove pycharm-community`) the snap version and manually download and and use the [version you wish](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/previous.html). However, this was only temporary due to a (now solved) bug in the database navigator.

Running (rather than installation) instructions are [provided on this page](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/#section=linux).